# How to access containerized service web interface from Docker host?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, routing, docker

My home server is running Ubuntu (with the Desktop Environment installed). It hosts several docker containers for some services that are managed by web interface (Transmission, Sickrage, Openhab, Unifi controller,...).

Per preference, I used the following for the networking of the containers :

```
--net=macvlan
--ip=192.168.0.211
```

This way, I do not have the port issue (install the first one on port 8080, then next one uses by default 8080 too but then I need to put to 8081, but then I want to install a new service which has 8081 by default but still, I need to change it to something else...), here, I just take next available IP address for next service and voila.

When it comes to outside access, for security reason, I opened only one port for SSH access to my homeserver from the outside, then through tunneling, I have a VNC access available as well.

My problem : I can access my containers web interface from any computer in the local network except for the homeserver itself. Containers can access each others too. At home, that is not a big issue, but when accessing from outside it is.

As a result, I can not use my VNC access to administer those services.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here : https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/get-started-macvlan/#macvlan-bridge-mode-example-usage

I needed to create a new network interface that is actually bridging with the macvlan :

```
ip link add mac0 link enp3s0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.0.199/24 dev mac0
ifconfig mac0 up
```

Commands need elevated privileges.

All became OK right away.